# Utilizar certificados de SOAP en Java 8

Tags: java-8, soap, certificado-ssl, wsdl

Tengo que llamar desde mi aplicación desarrollado con Java 8 a un webservice de SOAP (tengo el WSDL y en SOAPUI funciona) que contiene un certificado publico .cer y un certificado privado .p12 con su contraseña pero no sé cómo. He mirado en los foros y no he encontrado nada. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.